# ReactJS & Enzyme: Matching elements contents to string

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I have simple Intro component in React.js which renders a h1 and a p.

I am trying to write a test for the passed h1 & p strings with Enzyme but I'm unable to do this. What is wrong with this code?

```
it('description of element is okay <p>', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Intro title="Heading of element" description="Description of element" />);
  expect(wrapper.find('p').text().to.contain("Description of element")); // This is not working!
});
```

If I console log the `wrapper.find('p').text()` it's not undefined... And yet the console says like this:

```
  1) (Component) Intro contains a single <p>:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'contain' of undefined
  at Context.<anonymous> (test/components/alerts/alert.spec.js:19:12)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably assertion should look like:

```
expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).to.contain('Description of element')
```

`expect` works like:

```
expect(something).to.do.something
```

Answer (score 3):

New API to check string content is

```
expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).toContain('text to check')
```

For reference please check [jest toContain documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tocontainitem)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.to.contain` on the enzyme wrapper, not on the expect object. So instead of this:

```
expect(wrapper.find('p').text().to.contain("Description of element"));
```

You should have:

```
expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).to.contain("Description of element");
```